using Adaptive cards in emails
I’m using Power Automate to send emails, and I want to include Adaptive Cards in those emails. Specifically, I need to create an adaptive card that contains an action button, which, when clicked, saves data to a SharePoint list.
I have already created a simple adaptive card without an action button, but I’m facing two issues:

The adaptive card is not being displayed in the email.
I’m unsure how to add and configure an action button that will save data to SharePoint.
Here’s a brief outline of the steps I’ve followed in my flow so far.



Could someone guide me on how to resolve the display issue and complete the flow to achieve the desired functionality?

Which action are you using in flow?

In the send an email step you should not be wrapping the outputs in a script tag.  Nothing ever should display in script tags.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
